# how to share a rake variable in the code it invokes?

Tags: ruby, rspec, appium, rake-task, rakefile

What I need is basically send a target argument and use it in my RSpec tests, e.g.:

```
$ rake unistall_and_run[test_spec.rb]
```

Rakefile:

```
desc 'uninstall app to run tests'
  task :uninstall_and_run, [:arg] do |t, arg|
    #note this, i will explain later
    start_driver(fullReset: true)

    oi = arg.to_s.split('"')[1]
    file_dir = (project_home + '/spec/' + oi)
    exec "rspec #{file_dir}"
  end
```

`start_driver` is called on that line, but when I run the tests (`exec "rspec ..."`), it is called again and the args I passed is overwritten by the default (because its on RSpec config).

What I'd like to do is, on my RSpec file check if it was already called and don't run again.

Here is the start_driver method:

`def start_driver(options= {})
    if options.empty?
      capabilities = caps
    else
      capabilities = caps(options)
    end
    $appium = Appium::Driver.new(caps: capabilities)
    $browser = $appium.start_driver
    Appium.promote_appium_methods RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup
  end`

Comment: I don't understand "the args I passed is overwritten by the default". `start_driver` doesn't use `arg`. Are you trying to not run `start_driver` when it's called somewhere else when you run rspec, or are you trying to pass `arg` into something called by rspec?

Comment: i created this method to receive args: `def start_driver(options= {})
    if options.empty?
      capabilities = caps
    else
      capabilities = caps(options)
    end
    $appium = Appium::Driver.new(caps: capabilities)
    $browser = $appium.start_driver
    Appium.promote_appium_methods RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup
  end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i found a way to do it. Its not beautiful though. I save a file with the args I want when run rake:

```
    desc 'uninstall app to run tests'
      task :uninstall_and_run, [:arg] do |t, arg|
        send_custom_caps(fullReset: true)
        oi = arg.to_s.split('"')[1]
        file_dir = (project_home + '/spec/' + oi)
        exec "rspec #{file_dir}"
      end
```

and the `send_custom_caps` method is:

```
  def send_custom_caps(*opts)
    file = File.new(custom_caps_file, "w+")
    File.open(file, 'w') do |f|
      f.write(opts)
    end
  end
```

now the ruby code itself (in this case, my spec config) will check if there is custom args before `start_driver`. Here is my custom `start_driver` method (which I renamed):

```
  def start_appium_driver (options= {})
    if options.empty?
      get_caps
      if $custom_args
        capabilities = caps($custom_args)
      else
        capabilities = caps
      end
    else
      capabilities = caps(options)
    end
    $appium = Appium::Driver.new(caps: capabilities)
    $browser = $appium.start_driver
    Appium.promote_appium_methods RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup
  end
```

and `get_caps`

```
  def get_caps
    if File.exist?(custom_caps_file) #$custom_args
      file = File.read(custom_caps_file)
      $custom_args = eval(file)
      File.delete (custom_caps_file)
    end
    $custom_args unless $custom_args.defined?
  end
```

probably this is not the best solution, but it is working ok for me :)